# Customising Menu component in ANT Design using typescript

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

Each of these menus renders a new page. I want it in such a way that I should be able to click Agents and it should render a page, and its children when clicked should render a page respectively.

Here's what my menu looks like...

menu content image:

[image]

In ANTD, it only toggles when clicking Agents but I don't want it to not be only a toggle, but it should be clickable and render a page too.

What do I do?